# How can I make this double for each loop work?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to make a custom discord client for the apple watch with SwiftUI. I have to use a double for each loop to display the title channels(parent channels) with the normal text chats(child channels). When I run the code, I only get the result of the for each loop. Does someone know how to solve this?

```
struct ChannelsView: View {

    var serverId: String

    var body: some View {
        List{

            ForEach(NetworkHandler.parentChannels){parentChannel in

                Text(parentChannel.name)
                    .font(.headline)

                ForEach(parentChannel.childChannels){channel in

                    NavigationLink(destination: MessagesContentView(channelId: channel.id, channelName: channel.name)){
                        ChannelView(name: channel.name)
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Channels")
        .onAppear(){
            NetworkHandler.getChannels(serverId: self.serverId)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is the double?

Comment: @koen I have used to for each loops.

Comment: If I correctly understood your goal you need Section(s)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, I thought he meant `double` as a value.

Comment: @Asperi yes sections